wc_get_products not returning all products - how do I trigger to fetch all?
I am having the following code:
$args = array(
    'limit' => -1,  // Attempt to fetch all products
    'return' => 'ids' // Fetch only IDs to optimize performance; remove this to get full product objects
);

$product_ids = wc_get_products($args);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($product_ids);
echo "</pre>";

This gives the following output:
Array
(
    [0] => 496
    [1] => 106
    [2] => 103
    [3] => 58
)

However, I am having 9 products in WooCommerce.
The following code
function dispProduct($id)
{
    $productArray = array(
        'product_id'       => wc_get_product($id)->get_id(),
        'name'             => wc_get_product($id)->get_name(),
        'sku'              => wc_get_product($id)->get_sku(),
        'price'            => wc_get_product($id)->get_price(),
        'stock_status'     => wc_get_product($id)->get_stock_status(),
        'total_sales'      => wc_get_product($id)->get_total_sales(),
        'regular_price'    => wc_get_product($id)->get_regular_price(),
        'sale_price'       => wc_get_product($id)->get_sale_price(),
        // Add more attributes as needed
    );
    return $productArray;
}


echo "<pre>";
print_r(dispProduct(620));
echo "</pre>";

returns
Array
(
    [product_id] => 620
    [name] => Wordfence Premium
    [sku] => 
    [price] => 1116
    [stock_status] => instock
    [total_sales] => 0
    [regular_price] => 1116
    [sale_price] => 
)

That means, product 620 can be found.
If I go to my products in WooCommerce, click on Quick Edit under product 620, and just hit the "Update" button - without changing anything, then the first code returns
Array
(
    [0] => 620
    [1] => 496
    [2] => 106
    [3] => 103
    [4] => 58
)

But I cannot see any significant differences between 620 and 496 (before or after I update the product using Quick Edit), besides the obvious differences like price, name , sku and so forth.
How can I get ALL the products from WooCommerce?

Since version 3, WooCommerce is migrating to custom tables (like wp_wc_product_meta_lookup) and use special caching processes via transients, so that why some products doesn't show up when using wc_get_products() and appear after updating them via quick edit (or via the update button in admin product edit pages).

That makes sense! Do I have to query the wp_wc_products_meta_lookup table to get all the products, or do I have to trigger something, so that table is being populated somehow? Or what can I do to resolve the problem?

I don't know how you have set your products (importing them maybe), so the problem is in the way you added/imported those products... You should always use WC_Productset methods and always save the product using the save() method at the end.

They've been added manually, using the WordPress/WooCommerce backend.

That is not normal as when setting up a product in the backend (with publish status, visible, with a price and a name), it should appear when querying it with wc_get_products…

That's what I thought - so there might be something I can do.
If the problem only existed in my setup, I simply would "update" all the products using Quick Edit. But I cannot be sure, others won't experience the same problem.
Would you reckon, I could query the database on __posts where type=product, perhaps with status=published?

You should check in Admin WooCommerce > Status to see if there is not something wrong in the config, maybe enable temporarily WP_Debug… It could be also some 3rd Party plugin that is making trouble. Also In WooCommerce > Status > Tools, you can: Verify and Update database, Clear Transients (related to Products)…


If you're only getting 4 products instead of the expected 10 when attempting to fetch all products using wc_get_products(), it's likely due to the default product visibility settings in WooCommerce.

By default, WooCommerce only includes published products in the query results.
To ensure that all products, regardless of their publication status, are included in the query results, you can use the status parameter and set it to 'any'. Here's how you can modify your $args array:
    $args = array(
    'limit'  => -1,     // Attempt to fetch all products
    'return' => 'ids',  // Fetch only IDs to optimize performance
    'status' => 'any',  // Include products with any status ()
);

$product_ids = wc_get_products($args);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($product_ids);
echo "</pre>";


Thank you, Ankur Modi. I already tried that, but that doesn't work. But isn't it curious, it works (without the "any", if I quick-edit the product, and just hit "Update", without changing something?

As far as I know, two tables are being updated when clicking the Update button in Quick Edit: _posts and _term_relationships.
However, I can't see any changes in either one. But something has to be changed, because the product suddenly shows up in the array/object (whatever it is) after that "update button" was hit.

The solution I found is the following:
global $wpdb;
$product_ids = $wpdb->get_col("SELECT ID FROM {$wpdb->posts} WHERE post_type = 'product' AND post_status = 'publish'");

$products = array();
foreach ($product_ids as $product_id) {
    $products[] = wc_get_product($product_id);
}

This returns all the products.

This is the same thing as if you use WordPress way like $product_ids = get_posts(['post_type' => 'product', 'post_status' => 'any', 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'fields' => 'ids']);
